# In Linux kernel terms, what does "freeable memory" mean on Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-rds

What does Amazon mean by "freeable memory" on an RDS instance?  Is it filesystem buffers + free memory, or filesystem buffers + free memory - dirty buffers, or... ?